# Vim Script: User-defined command with "prefix"

Tags: vim, scripting, command, user-defined

I have created a simple user-defined command using the following vim script

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=file EE :call EE(<f-args>)

function! EE(...)
  if filereadable(expand(a:1))
    exec 'edit ' . a:1
  endif
endfunction
```

`:EE file` will open a file (like the built-in command `":edit file`)

But unlike `:tab edit file` the command `:tab EE file` will not open a new tab.

Is it possible to enhance the script so that a "prefix" like `:tab` or `:vert` could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, the prefix command isn't exposed to custom commands; it would be great to have a `v:prefixcommand` variable that one could evaluate.

You so far have to write separate alternative commands, e.g. `:TEE` for `:tab EE`.